# How to add only the required number of inputs in an array in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, data-structures

### **My question is: How to add only the required number of inputs in an array in Kotlin?**

### Input Format

1. The first line of input will contain a single integer, the number of test cases. Then the test cases follow.
2. Each test case consists of 2 lines of input.
3. **The first line of input of each test case contains a single integer, N, which is the total number of problems that the person has added to his to-do list.**
4. The second line of input of each test case contains N space-separated integers (eg: d1, d2, d3.....)

My doubt is how to mention the required number of inputs (that should only be counted in the array)

[Link to the original problem:](https://www.codechef.com/submit/TODOLIST)

### Sample Inputs

[Inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXK3O.png)

### Sample Output

[Outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr4qg.png)

Please help me to solve this in Kotlin.

My incompleted code without the 3rd step

```
fun main() {
val n = readLine()!!.toInt()
repeat(n) {
    val difficultyRating = readLine()!!.split(" ").map { it.toInt() }

    difficultyRating
        .count { it >= 1000 }
        .let { println(it) }
     }
}
```

Comment: I think you're misreading the problem - the **first** line is the number of *test cases*. Then **each test case** is two lines, the *first* is the number of items, the *second* is the actual items, separated by spaces. So your `repeat` block needs to handle that pair of lines. The problem doesn't actually say you need an *array* - you could just use `take` on your list of `Int`s to grab as many as you need. (You could chain `toIntArray()` on the end if you really wanted)

Comment: Can you please re-send me the code using **take** keyword?

Comment: and I need to explicitly mention that **N** number of inputs should come to the **Int** list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how we need to code to solve this. (Thank you for the helps)

```
fun main() {
val n = readLine()!!.toInt()  //number of times the program should be repeated
repeat(n) {
    val x = readLine()!!.toInt()
    /*this is how we can explicitly mention that "n" number of inputs only should be
    considered when running the program  using (take() function)*/
    val difficultyRating = readLine()!!.split(" ").map { it.toInt() }.take(x)

    difficultyRating
        .count { it >= 1000 }
        .let { println(it) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's more typical to work with Lists than arrays. Since all the difficulty ratings come in on a single line, instead of repeating or using a loop, you can `split` the input string. After you split them into a List, they are still Strings, so you you need to convert when comparing them to a number.

```
fun main() {
    val numberOfTestCases = readln().toInt()
    repeat(numberOfTestCases) {
        readln() // we don't need to read number of items, but we need to skip the line
        readln().split(" ")
            .count { it.toInt() >= 1000 }
            .let { println(it) }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1)5 (**number of total test cases**)-------
**first test case starts here**
2)3 **only three inputs should be considered in the Int list**-------
3)2000 1000 1000 5000 6000  **user input of Int list**---------
>>>>4)5 **output should be 3 but 5 came (3 is the answer I NEED here) because I enterd 3 **

Comment: I think you're using `>= 1000` instead of `> 1000`. You only want to count items **more than** 1000, not items that are **at least** 1000.

Comment: No, for example, if I entered 3 and if I give a list of integers for Eg: (2000 1000 5000 6000 4000) the output should be 3 (because 2000 1000 and 5000 are greater than or equal to 1000) the main thing is the program should not consider the 6000 and 4000 because I have entered as 3 in the before the line of input (so it should only consider the first 3 inputs of the **Int list**) (sorry my English is poor. hope you can understand the logic)

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand what you mean. In the website you linked you don’t enter any inputs. That’s not part of the problem. Are you asking how to do something that is not part of the problem on that web site?